# How to persist non-standard arrays with jdbc + postgres?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

How do I go about persisting Java arrays with JDBC and Postgres?
I know that you can persist standard arrays just by passing them to `preparedStatement.setObject()`, for example, `String[]` will be persisted as `text[]`. However, what if I want to persist something like `PGInterval[][][]` which would correspond to `interval[][][]` in the database? When I pass it to `.setObject()`, it errors, saying it cannot cast object of type `[[[Lorg.postgresql.util.PGInterval;`. How would I do that? Or for example, how would I persist `OffsetDateTime[][]` which corresponds to `timestamptz[][]`?

How should I persist an array of a composite type? For example if the type is

```sql
CREATE TYPE test AS (
  a integer,
  b integer
);
```

And I make a POJO to match

```java
class Test {
  Integer a;
  Integer b;

  // constructors + getters/setters omitted
}
```

How would I go about persisting `Test[][][][]` as `test[][][][]`?